# Application to manage Windows file associations

Tags: gratis, windows-7

Looking for a reliable and free-of-cost Windows 7 compatible application to mange Windows file associations.

The one integrated into Windows XP wasn't bad.  The one integrated into Windows 7 is just sad.

Reliability is essential.

Open-source always a plus.

Answer (score 3):

Nirsoft's [FileTypesMan](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/file_types_manager.html) does what you're asking and is freeware.

I have used it, I don't remember that I had anything complicated to do with it - but the few times I've needed it, it's come in handy

It looks like this:
[image: FileTypesMan screenshot]

Comment: Thanks.  Have you used it, and is it reliable for you?  I had tried an early version of it, and had trouble with it.  Is it reliable now?

Comment: I have used it yes, I don't remember that I had anything complicated to do with it - but the few times I've needed it, it's come in handy

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the program so we could see what its like?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs there is a screenshot on the linked page

Comment: @aland Please do add it to your answer here. We prefer the answers to work even after the links die. The goal is that readers can vet the suitability of a program just by looking at the answer here without having to follow any links.

Comment: While I understand your reasoning for other SE sites, I don't see how it applies here. If the link has died, the program is presumably no longer available - so I don't see how a screenshot is going to help anyone manage their WIndows file associations.

Comment: @aland If the link rots but the screenshot indicates that its a good fit the reader can go out and search for an archived version of that program; Or in situations where projects change the URL of theirs. Also, we want people to be able to vet answers by the content here on SR.SE and prefer it if they don't have to leave the site to get their information.